# why windows shows The system cannot find the file specified?

Tags: python

As i am a new baby in phython ,i didn't able to find the problem.here is my code..

```
import os

def rename_files():

#get the all files in the directory
file_list = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\squalporeover\Desktop\prank')
print ( file_list )

#rename each file
for file_name in file_list:
    os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,'0123456789'))

rename_files()
```

Answer (score 2):

`file_list` just contains the file names, not the full paths. You need to pass the path+name to os.rename.

```
path = r'C:\Users\squalporeover\Desktop\prank'
file_list = os.listdir(path)

for file_name in file_list:
    full_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    os.rename(full_path, file_name.translate(None,'0123456789'))
```